# Finding value of c and n0 in Big-O analysis

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I have this relationship (n^2 + 7n - 10) ^3 = O(n^6)

I need to prove it is true. I know it is true but to be able to prove it I must find values of n0 and c. By trial and error I have found that this equation is true for n0 = 2 and c = 8.

But it doesn’t hold for n0 = 3 and c = 8.

According to my understanding it should hold for all n > n0 with the same constant c. Is that correct? Is there any easy method for solving this kind of equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a better question for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). To answer your question, n = 2 just so happens to work with c = 8, but when c = 8, n0 actually needs to be at least 5. When n > 5 with c = 8, it will work.

Comment: Oh thankyou for pointing out. In graph, both curves seem to be cutting each other many times. I guess that is because it's a tight bound really and n^6 = theeta (n^6) eventually.

Comment: There are so many stackexchange sites I might have to do a linear search next time to figure out where to post questions! joking.. thanks

Comment: Yeah, they really should add math support to Stack Overflow, though. I should post a question on the meta.